# Dynamic Netezza pivot

Tags: sql, pivot, netezza

I can mimic the pivot function in Netezza by using a series of case statements

i.e

sum(case when substr(CALL_TIME,1,6) = '201701'  then  costs else 0 end) as "Jan 2017",

sum(case when substr(CALL_TIME,1,6) = '201702'  then  costs else 0 end)as "Feb 2017",

sum(case when substr(CALL_TIME,1,6) = '201703'  then  costs else 0 end) as "Mar 2017"

Is it possible to do the same but with dynamic column names so I don't have a separate case statement for each month please? I need to do something similar but by day and its going to be a pain.

Many thanks and regards,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will need to create your own pivot function. This brilliant piece of code is documented at [dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/).

Once you do that, you can easily pivot your costs with something similar to the following:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE (pivot ('select office, to_char(call_time, ''YYYYMM-MON'') themonth, sum(costs) cost_sum from brianl.deleteme_tbl group by  to_char(call_time, ''YYYYMM-MON''), office'));
```

My deleteme_tbl has office, costs, and call_time. The actual result from running this is:

```
OFFICE    201701-JAN 201702-FEB 201703-MAR 201704-APR 201705-MAY 201706-JUN 201707-JUL 201708-AUG 201709-SEP
Anchorage 45         23         15         25         25         5          15         50         30
```

I prefaced the dates with YYYYMM so that the columns would appear in sorted order.

Comment: I may be blind, but the actual code for the pivot() function is nowhere to be found on the page you link to (or subsequent links)... please help... furthermore the PL/SQL on oracle may not be compatible with netezza, more so for stored procedures than functions....

Comment: @LarsGOlsen Under the resource section: Download the sources for this article: AntonsPivoting.zip. Connected as SCOTT, first run pivotFun.sql, then either pivot.sql or pivot_distances.sql.  The AntonsPivoting.zip link is [link](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/images/antonsPivoting.zip)

Comment: Thanks - as I suspected: I was blind :)